# How to require python's `with` statement on an object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am writing a Database Access Layer using python's SQLAlchemy kit.  I have been doing some research on the best way to make the layer thread safe and resource responsible.  To accomplish this I have stumbled upon the `NullPool` object that can be passed during the db engine creation.

To make the DAOs "resource responsible" I have considered closing the session at the end of a try/catch/finally block, however I did not want to take this route as I want the connection to stay open for as long as the consumer needs the DAO for database operations.  As a way to close the connection at the end of the object's life-cycle, I wanted to use the `with` statements `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods.  The enter method will return the instance of the object and the exit method will perform the `session.close()` at the end of the object's use.

What I want to do, however, is to require that the object be instantiated with the python `with` statement in such a way that if the object is created in any other way, the instantiation fails.

Is there a way to accomplish this?  I have included the class and the usage statement below:

```
class RegionDAO(declarative_base()):                                             

     __tablename__ = 'region'                                                     

     region_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)                                
     country_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)                               
     description = Column(String, nullable=False)                                 
     code = Column(String, nullable=False)                                        
     region_type = Column(Integer)                                                
     sort_order = Column(Integer)                                                 

     def __init__(self):                                                          
         connection, meta = PG.get_connection()                                   
         Session = sessionmaker(bind=connection)                                  
         self.session = Session()                           

     def __enter__(self):                                                         
         return self                                                              

     def select_all(self):                                                        
         for row in self.session.query(RegionDAO).all():                          
             print("[" + row.description + "] - [" + row.code + "]")              

     def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):                          
         print("Exit being called, cleaning up session")                          
         self.session.close()                                                     

 #                                                                                
 # main                                                                           
 #                                                                                

 if __name__ == "__main__":

     # This should succeed                                                       
     with RegionDAO() as r:                                                      
         r.select_all()                                                          

     # This should fail                                                                                  
     r = RegionDAO()                                                              
     r.select_all()
```

EDIT - After reading some of the comments, I think I may have caused some confusion.  What my ultimate goal is - that when the object is done being used, the connection is closed. (connection in this case being the session due to the use of the NullPool object)

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good idea. What if the class is to be encapsulated in another class? How would instantiation of that class return to the caller?

Comment: You could set a flag in ``__enter__``, and raise an exception in ``select_all`` (and all other data access methods) if that flag isn't set.

Comment: Use a wrapper that instantiates the real object within `__enter__()`. But really: don't

Comment: The expression right after with is an arbitrary expression and there's no obvious way to make it 'know' it's being used in with. But even if there were, this seems like a bad idea as it violates the implied contracts of instance creation (and, really, with).

Comment: @ignacio - I did not consider this.  Ultimately I also wish to follow best practice.  Perhaps it should just be left to the user to know how to use the DAO

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this edit, the facility for that in Python is `with` and context managers. You seem to be using them already.

Comment: I am indeed using the `with` statement here.  However I was seeking to guarantee it.  I would like some error thrown if it isn't cleaned up - which is why I originally asked if there was a way to throw an error if the object wasn't used in this way.

Comment: You guarantee it by using `with`. This is somewhat the nature of a highly-dynamic language, trying to hack or design around it is probably more detrimental than useful since it, among many other things, would go against the basic expectations of users of such code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not suggesting you go this way, as this is rather against typical assumptions in OOP, but if you **really need** to accomplish this you can make sure that you cannot call methods of an object instantiated outside **with**, but there is simply no way of forbidding instance creation as such.

Since context manager does provide anything to the constructor, but rather just calls **enter** and **exit** the only way I can see is to make sure that all the methods your class provide simply first check whether **enter** was called before, furthermore, I would move all the logic to **enter** rather then constructor (since if you want to disallow any other usage what is the point of doing anything in init which is always followed by enter?)

```
 def __init__(self):                                                          
     self.session = None                       

 def __enter__(self): 
     connection, meta = PG.get_connection()                                   
     Session = sessionmaker(bind=connection)                                  
     self.session = Session()    
     return self                                                              

 def select_all(self):
     if self.session is None:
       raise Exception('This class can only be used as a context manager')                                                        
     for row in self.session.query(RegionDAO).all():                          
         print("[" + row.description + "] - [" + row.code + "]")
```

or if you want to keep your previous approach, just add a new flag in **enter**

```
 def __init__(self):                                                          
     connection, meta = PG.get_connection()                                   
     Session = sessionmaker(bind=connection)                                  
     self.session = Session()    
     self._is_context_manager = False

 def __enter__(self): 
     self._is_context_manager = True
     return self                                                              

 def select_all(self):
     if not self._is_context_manager:
       raise Exception('This class can only be used as a context manager')                                                        
     for row in self.session.query(RegionDAO).all():                          
         print("[" + row.description + "] - [" + row.code + "]")
```

Comment: The poster seems to want to prevent instantiation outside of `with`, though.

Comment: @pvg the example provided in the question says nothing about instantiation, only about calling methods on instances created outside.

Comment: Does it? I guess I don't see what would prevent that `__init__` from returning

Comment: @pvg that's what the `self._is_context_manager` part does :)
The `__init__` is not relevant here, the poster wants the protection on the `select_all()` method.

Comment: I added a sentence at the very begining to make things clear - we forbid calling methods on instances created outside with, but there is no way of figuring out whether __init__ itself was called inside with or not.

Comment: @lejlot the question specifically says 'instantiation', so I don't think breaking all the methods is the same thing. Object still gets instantiated.

Comment: @Wolph poster specifically says 'What I want to do, however, is to require that the object be instantiated with the python with statement in such a way that if the object is created in any other way, the instantiation fails.'

Comment: @pvg - OP asks about "instantiation" yet provides an example of actually calling a method. These are potentially two questions in one. The (updated) answer clearly states that the first one cannot be accomplished (there is no way of figuring out whether __init__ was called during "with" or not) while the second one can be achieved with a simple solution provided.

Comment: I should have made myself more clear, it seems.  My ultimate goal is to ensure that the connection is closed once the object is done being used.  I will update my question.

Comment: In such case first solution (moving everything to __enter__) is what you are looking for - session will be created iff enter is called, which happens inside with block.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - considering everything I have read here I may just leave the `with` usage to the user to implement but you have indeed answered my question.